# How to add files or libraries for autocompletion to Geany? (Vulkan headers in my case)

Tags: autocomplete, vulkan, geany

I'm going through the process of learning Vulkan, and it's getting rather tedious sometimes to do some long and complicated names of fields and enums. I know VSCode can autocomplete just fine, so it has to be picking up the data from a header somewhere.
How can find this headers and point Geany to it?